# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in setInterval callback

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a script which gets the updated of image src every 10 seconds using selenium-webdriver.

This runs on the node server.
I am not able to understand why during compile time javascript gives error of **"SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"** on driver variable inside setInterval callback.

Is not "deiver" variable is in the scope of "example" funcetion and setInterval callback should be able access it?

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');
var firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
var FirefoxProfile = require('firefox-profile');

FirefoxProfile.copyFromUserProfile({name: 'foobar'}, function(err, profile) {
var opts = new firefox.Options();
opts.setProfile(profile.profileDir);
(async function example() {

    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').setFirefoxOptions(opts).build();

    try {

        await driver.get('http://google.com');
        var myTimer = setInterval(()=>{
            var image = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img"));  // error is here
            var imageSrc = image.getAttribute('src');
        },1000*10);

    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } finally {
        await driver.quit();
    }

})();

});
```

ERROR :

```
/home/vikas/Development/node/webdriver/index.js:16
            var image = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img"));
                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:537:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:598:3
```

Comment: You can only use await inside async function. Your callback was not marked as async.

Comment: Your callback is not an `async function`, so you cannot use `await` inside of it.

Comment: how can i make a callback as async, i want to get the image src every 10 secinds

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achive. `setInterval` will run "forever". Do you want this test to just hang? What are you going to do with those images? Is there any stop condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't provide any stop condition you could replace `setInterval` with an infinite loop

```
// promisified "setTimeout" to use later
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

(async function example() {

    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').setFirefoxOptions(opts).build();

    try {

        await driver.get('http://google.com');

        while(true) { // run forever or use some condition to stop
           await delay(1000 * 10) // just wait 10 seconds

           var image = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img"));
           var imageSrc = image.getAttribute('src'); // do something useful, I guess
        }

    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } finally {
        await driver.quit();
    }

})();
```